# How to reuse the same prefab with unique name & tag and Add into a C# List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D and C# and have been struggling to find a convenient way to reuse the same prefab, with unique name & tag, and Add it to a List.

I have the following test code:

```
public class testScript : MonoBehaviour {

public static List<string> cardDeckBackListNames = new List<string> {
    "HAB", "H2B", "H3B", "H4B", "H5B", "H6B", "H7B", "H8B", "H9B", "H10B", "HJB", "HQB", "HKB",};
private GameObject temp_GameObject;
public static List<GameObject> master_GameObject_List = new List<GameObject> ();




// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    temp_GameObject = Resources.Load ("BackSide") as GameObject;
    temp_GameObject.name = cardDeckBackListNames [0];
    temp_GameObject.tag = cardDeckBackListNames [0];
    master_GameObject_List.Add (temp_GameObject);

    temp_GameObject = Resources.Load ("BackSide") as GameObject;
    temp_GameObject.name = cardDeckBackListNames [1];
    temp_GameObject.tag = cardDeckBackListNames [1];
    master_GameObject_List.Add (temp_GameObject);

    int yy = 0;
    foreach (GameObject aGO in master_GameObject_List) {
        print ("After loading: " + aGO.tag + " #"+ yy);
        yy++;
    }
    
    print ("master_GameObject_List.Count: " + master_GameObject_List.Count);
}
}
```

Get the following result:

> After loading: H2B #0
>
> After loading: H2B #1
>
> master_GameObject_List.Count: 2

My conclusion is that I cannot use the same GameObject and "only" modify the name & tag as it seems like when i do that it also modify all objects that i have loaded into the List.

As i am very new at C# i would like to ask what would be the correct way of doing what i am trying to do? 1.) reusing the same prefab with unique name & tag, 2.) load the "unique" objects into a List

ps. I initially used a "foreach" loop but removed that to be able to do a clean and simple test.

Comment: I see the result you are getting. Could you show and explain further what you want the result to be? Do you want these different named GameObjects in the scene?

Comment: @FunctionR What I am trying to do is to create a List with unique GameObjects reusing the same prefab. I then want to load them as unique objects (not in the test code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

When you use `Resources.Load()` you loading the prefab, but every time you make a change you are editing the same prefab.

Here is a picture of the editor showing you what you are pointing to:
[image]

---

#### Solution

Since you want unique `GameObjects` the first thing you need to do is [**Instantiate**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) them. After that you can edit each individual `GameObject` as you like.

```
void Start () 
{
    temp_GameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BackSide")) as GameObject;
    temp_GameObject.name = cardDeckBackListNames[0];
    temp_GameObject.tag = cardDeckBackListNames[0];
    master_GameObject_List.Add(temp_GameObject);

    temp_GameObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BackSide")) as GameObject;
    temp_GameObject.name = cardDeckBackListNames[1];
    temp_GameObject.tag = cardDeckBackListNames[1];
    master_GameObject_List.Add(temp_GameObject);
}
```

---

These are the results:

[image]

Comment: Also it might be a good idea to stop using `Load()` entirely and use Dependency Injection instead. Just declare your prefabs a public parameters and drag and drop in the editor!

Comment: @FunctionR that made it, a BIG thank you for this help, really appreciate it and I learned something new as well :-)

Comment: @PeterK No problem. @Marconius Also it is true that drag and drop can replace `Load()` but it won't solve the problem when renaming the prefab, it will still point to the same prefab. Sometimes it is more useful to use `Load()`.